# How to rearrange menu bar to show mode-specific items first

Tags: menu-bar

The Emacs menu bar places mode-specific menus after most of the default menu items, but before the "Help" menu*. Specifically: "File", "Edit", "Options", "Buffers", "Tools", mode-specific menu items, "Help". For example:

- Lisp Interaction mode:

  [image: Emacs menu bar in Lisp interaction mode]
- Prolog mode:

  [image: Emacs menu bar in Prolog mode]

Is there a way to rearrange the menu items such that the mode-specific menu items always appear before all the other menu items? For example, in Lisp Interaction mode, I would like the "Lisp-Interaction" menu item to be the first menu item (i.e. appearing to before "File").

---

* The "Help" menu always appears last because of the variable `menu-bar-final-items` which is `'(help-menu)` by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the value of the variable [`menu-bar-final-items`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Menu-Bar.html#index-menu_002dbar_002dfinal_002ditems):

```lisp
(setq menu-bar-final-items '(file edit options buffer tools help-menu))
```

Example results:

- Lisp Interaction mode:

  [image: Rearranged Emacs menu bar in Lisp Interaction mode]
- Prolog mode:

  [image: Rearranged Emacs menu bar in Prolog mode]

The menu bar has been changed to show mode-specific menu items first.

Answer (score 0):

I do exactly that in [Menu-Bar+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MenuBarPlus) (code: [`menu-bar+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/menu-bar%2b.el).

This is what I do, for that. First, I add a divider pseudo-menu:

```lisp
(defvar menu-bar-divider-menu (make-sparse-keymap "Divider"))
(define-key global-map [menu-bar divider] (cons "||" menu-bar-divider-menu))
(define-key menu-bar-divider-menu [menu-bar-divider-hint]
  '("<-- Current mode menus to left.   ||   Common menus to right -->"
    . describe-menubar))
```

Then I move all of the standard menus, plus a couple Menu-Bar+ menus, to `menu-bar-final-items`:

```lisp
(setq menu-bar-final-items
      (append '(divider file edit options buffer tools search)
              (and (boundp 'menu-bar-frames-menu) '(frames))
              (and (boundp 'menu-bar-doremi-menu) '(doremi))
              '(help-menu)
              (and (fboundp 'show-tool-bar-for-one-command) '(pop-up-tool-bar))))
```

You can click the divider, `\\`, to show help about the menu bar (command `describe-menubar`), which is this (it describes the predefined menus for Menu-Bar+):

```lisp
(defun describe-menubar ()
  "Explain the menu bar, in general terms."
  (interactive)
  (with-output-to-temp-buffer "*Help*"
    (princ (substitute-command-keys
            "To the right of the menu bar divider (\"||\") are the general menus
that usually appear in every buffer.  To the left of this symbol, there
may also be additional menus that are specific to the buffer's mode
\(use `\\[describe-mode]' for information on a buffer's mode).

The general menus are as follows:

    Buffers  File  Tools  Edit  Frames  Do Re Mi  Help

Use the \"Frames\" menu to resize, tile, and hide/show frames.
Use the \"Do Re Mi\" menu to incrementally change things.
The \"Help\" menu extends the \"Help\" menu described in the Emacs manual (`\\[info]').

For information on a menu item, use the \"This\" item in the \"Describe\"
submenu of the \"Help\" menu."))
    (if (fboundp 'help-print-return-message)
        (help-print-return-message)
      (print-help-return-message))
    (with-current-buffer standard-output
      (help-mode)
      (buffer-string))))  ; Return the text we displayed.
```

Because local menus are added before `menu-bar-final-items`, then end up at the left of the menu-bar.  So the effect is to have, from left to right: local menus, divider, non-local menus.